# Nginx, limiting request per second for uwsgi application

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, django, rate-limiting

How to set/estimate proper value for nginx's "limit_req_zone" and "limit_req"?
I have nginx as reverse-proxy for Django app. During loading for example admin panel (where Django request a lot of css/js files) I receiving more than ten 503's errors.

Current configuration:

```
limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=perip:5m rate=20r/s;
limit_req zone=perip burst=5 nodelay;
```

Is it a good practice, to set burst parameter for example to 20?
Is there maybe another way to handle it?

Comment: my question would be more why you getting 503. gets your server overloaded or bashed on request? do you use nginx as reverse proxy? If not it might a good thing to use a second instance one in front which you use to cache these request and offload thst from your "django" server

Comment: @djdomi 503 is thrown due to blocking rule (more requests than is currently allowed - parameter rate=20r/s).

Comment: why do you block it such low rate? evem my wiki has more as 31r/s for one Page

Comment: @djdomi to prevent from DDos attacks. My server is rather low-end machine.

Comment: then please add the specs of your server, ifi a ddos is incoming your server is mostly in any case the smallest member in the chain

Comment: @djdomi micro instance on google-cloud